# Apache mod_rewrite rule for sub directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration, url-rewriting

I am trying to set up a rewrite rule so that anything after localhost/test/{this} gets forwarded to localhost/test/index.php?{here}

I have access to the server and configuration currently looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/test/>
            AllowOverride All
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1      
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

But at the moment, instead of showing /localhost/test/index.php?something when visiting localhost/test/something it shows localhost/index.php so it's rewriting to the wrong place.. any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.. I found that whenever I included AllowOverride All it redirected to /index.php, then spotted I'd left a .htaccess file in there from testing earlier that was messing things up. Removed, updated my rule and now working. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess file in /var/www/test

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Should it not be possible to define as part of Directory instead of .htaccess?

Comment: I think if you put this will work, but i don't know for sure.